# How to generate a new HTML element each time a JS function is called

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have been working on a webapp that uses steam to log-in through passport and sessions. Lately I have been struggling with finding a good method to create persistent html on the page. Let me explain, here's my index.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include('partials/navbar') %>
<body>
<section id="chat"></section>
<section id="main" style="flexcol center" class="flexcol">
    <button id="newMatch">Create new match</button>
    <div class="match"></div>
</section>
</body>
<script src=".././scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src=".././scripts/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have tried to make a js function that inserts a new `<div class="match"></div>` every time it's called but wasn't successful. Here's the code:

```
//CONTENT GENERATOR
    let main = document.querySelector('#main');
    let matchDiv = document.createElement('div');
    let matchDivText = document.createElement('h3');
    
    function createMatch(){
        $(matchDivText).append('New match').appendTo($(matchDiv));
        $(matchDiv).addClass('match flex center').appendTo(main);
    };
    
    $('button').click(() => {
        createMatch();
    });
```

For now, my function is not really working perfectly, It does create a new DIV, append the h2 and add the class but if called multiple times it looks like this(called 3 times) :

[image: n]

My question is: How can i make the function create a new DIV each time and also how can I make these DIVS not go away after refresh ?

Comment: _"How can i make the function create a new DIV each time"_ - move statements with `createElement()` method call inside the function. _"how can I make these DIVS not go away after refresh ?"_ - you need to store the html content somewhere; localSotrage could be one of the option.

Comment: The main problem is that you create the two elements only once, instead of inside the `createMatch()` function. As for the "not go away after refresh", this depends on where you plan to store them. On the server so they will be visible for every user? In that case you need to send them to the server and render them in your template using a loop. Or you store them just inside the browser, for that you need localStorage. As for your code: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjk9hzs/1

Comment: You should not ask multiple questions (create new DIV, persist after refresh). Please focus on one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variables are not in the function, do this:

```
function createMatch () {
        let main = document.querySelector('#main');
        let matchDiv = document.createElement('div');
        let matchDivText = document.createElement('h3');
        $(matchDivText).append('New match').appendTo($(matchDiv));
        $(matchDiv).addClass('match flex center').appendTo(main);
    };
    
    $('button').click(() => {
        createMatch();
    });
```

Comment: You can't really do it after refresh without a server

Comment: what is your point exactly? What cannot be done? This is client code. No server involved, at least not for this part.

Comment: You could POST ( the window HTML or just any edits ) using AJAX to your server

Comment: Yes, you *could*, but why? Oh I see: the OP asked *two* questions... Missed that.

Comment: @trincot They are referring to OP's `and also how can I make these DIVS not go away after refresh?`

Comment: @trincot Every time you refresh, you are sending a request to your backend server, which responds with HTML, CSS, and JS. Therefore, to make HTML, CSS, and JS without the backend dynamically is... (I don't really know if it's impossible)

Comment: Sure, I know that. But yes, you can do it without server, like with localStorage.

Comment: Oh really! That's nice to know. I'll dig a little deeper and see what I can find :)

Comment: @cocolove if the solution was helpful and answered your question, please upvote and mark as answered. (It's helpful for other people)